# Weird Port in use issue under Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, windows-administration

I encountered a very common issue **Port 8080 already in use** when starting a Jakarta EE application server, such as GlassFish, WildFly, etc.

But I tried to find the application which use this port, failed to get the result.

- `netstat -aon| findstr :8080` get empty result, either normal users and administrator.
- In *Listening Ports* view in **Resource Monitor** window, can not find an application use this port.
- Used tools like [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) in a visual UI, also can not find any application is using this port.

I wonder is there any other reason to cause this port not available?

Comment: It works if you change WildFly port to 9090 (or any other ) https://www.baeldung.com/wildfly-change-default-port ? or any malware ?

Comment: Of course changing port number works.